# Getting Google App stats with python

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to scrape some web content to get stastics from google appstats that my google app generated. Please note this is different then google analytics.  I am using python 2.7.5.
The issue I am facing is the initial google authentication in my request.
I have the apis I need to call from google app stats but I keep getting a DENY in response back when I am using my own google appengine account credentials.  This results in a  redirect to accounts.google.com page.
I have tried several different approaches without a successfull login to accounts.google.com.

Anyone have any ideas on this?
More helpfull would be if you can point me to some good reference material

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code sample will allow you to get content of /secure page which protected by google login. Do not forget to set email, password and application ID. Then you can fetch other protected pages using this opener.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import logging

EMAIL = ''
PASSWORD = ''
APPID = 'YOURAPPID'

# Setup to be able to get the needed cookies that GAE returns
cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# This is the setup to construct the login URL for authentication.
authreq_data = urllib.urlencode({'Email': EMAIL,
                                 'Passwd': PASSWORD,
                                 'service': 'ah',
                                 'source': '',
                                 'accountType': 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE'})

# Get an AuthToken from Google Accounts
auth_req = urllib2.Request('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin',
                            data=authreq_data)
try:
  auth_resp = opener.open(auth_req)
  logging.info('Successful authorization as %s' % EMAIL)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
  logging.warning('Authorization as %s failed. '
                  'Please, check your email and password' % EMAIL)

auth_resp_body = auth_resp.read()
auth_resp_dict = dict(x.split('=')
                      for x in auth_resp_body.split('\n') if x)
authtoken = auth_resp_dict['Auth']

authreq_data = urllib.urlencode({'continue': 'http://%s.appspot.com/secure' % APPID,
                                 'auth': authtoken})
login_uri = ('http://%s.appspot.com/_ah/login?%s' % (APPID, authreq_data))

# Do the actual login and getting the cookies.
print opener.open(urllib2.Request(login_uri)).read()
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry Thanks very much for the support,and this was very successful. There was not a lot of resources out there explaining the finner points like what your example points out.